# How to fix this issue with delete object from array by title?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to delete object from array by title in this situation, but it doesnt work for me. Also, addItem work properly

```
addItem() {
    console.log(this.item.title + ' ' + this.item.quantity);
    this.ListOfUsedMaterials.push({ title: this.item.title, quantity: this.item.quantity});
    this.item.title = "";
    this.item.quantity = ""; 
}


//delete from array by title
deleteItem() {
    console.log("ID ARTIKLA: ", this.item.title);

    for (var i=0; i < this.ListOfUsedMaterials.length; i++) {
      if (this.ListOfUsedMaterials[i]["title"] == this.item.title) {
        this.ListOfUsedMaterials.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use filter :

```
deleteItemfromArray(title = this.item.title) {
  this.ListOfUsedMaterials = this.ListOfUsedMaterials
    .filter(item => item.title != title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this. we need to iterate loop from the end because here we are deleting the array element, I hope it helps you out.

```
deleteItem() {
console.log("ID ARTIKLA: ", this.item.title);
var i = 0;
for (i; i < this.ListOfUsedMaterials.length - 1; --i) {
   if (this.ListOfUsedMaterials[i]["title"] == this.item.title) {
      this.ListOfUsedMaterials.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

keep declaration `i` outside for loop because for loop tries to create new variable for every iteration.